# Algorithm to mark all factors of a given number as not prime (they are prime numbers though)

Tags: algorithm, math, dynamic-programming, primes, number-theory

I'have been trying to solve [this problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/FINDPRM/) all day, but I'm getting "time limit exceeded" again and again.

My Task: Given number N, I have to exclude all prime numbers between [2; N] that are factors of other numbers between this range [2; N].

Here's my code:

```
public class Main {

    public static final int SIEVE_LIMIT = 10000001;

    public static final boolean[] COMPOSITES = new boolean[SIEVE_LIMIT];

    private static final ArrayList<Integer> PRIMES = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main (String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

        BufferedReader inStream = null;
        BufferedWriter outStream = null;
        int numCases, curNum, counter;
        StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        boolean []temporary = null;

        COMPOSITES[0] = true;
        COMPOSITES[1] = true;

        for(int i = 2; i*i < SIEVE_LIMIT; i++){
            if(!COMPOSITES[i])
                for(int j = i*i; j < SIEVE_LIMIT; j+=i) {
                    COMPOSITES[j] = true;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 2; i < SIEVE_LIMIT; i++) {
          if (!COMPOSITES[i]) 
              PRIMES.add(i);
        }

        inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        outStream = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));

        numCases = Integer.parseInt(inStream.readLine());

        for(int i = 0; i < numCases; i++){

            curNum = Integer.parseInt(inStream.readLine());
            counter = 0;                        
            temporary = new boolean[SIEVE_LIMIT];

            **// I can't improve this part of the code**
            for(int j = curNum; j > (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(curNum)); j--){

                if(!temporary[j]){
                    for(int aPrime: PRIMES){

                    if(aPrime > (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(j))) break;

                    if(temporary[aPrime]) break;

                    if (j % aPrime == 0) {
                        temporary[aPrime] = true;

                    }                   
                }
            }
        }

        for(int j = 2; j <= curNum; j++) {
            if(!temporary[j] && !COMPOSITES[j])
            counter++;
        }
        //......

        resultBuilder.append(Integer.toString(counter) + '\n');         
    }

      inStream.close();
      outStream.write(resultBuilder.toString().trim() + '\n');
      outStream.close();   
    }
}
```

How can I write fast-running code for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### HINT 1

I think you need to take a more mathematical approach to this problem.

### HINT 2

What properties will your desired numbers have?

### HINT 3

You know a target number x will be prime, and also that it is not a factor of any number y<=n.

Consider y=2*x.  x is a factor of this, so if 2*x<=n, we know that x is not one of our target numbers.

### HINT 4

Try to find a fast way to count all primes p such that p<=n and 2*p > n.